# How to find all WebElements on page by presence of id?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I know I can find element by `id`:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='some_id']"));
```

And I can find all elements with this `id`, but I want to find all elements with an `id` attribute. I'm looking for something like:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id]"));
// or
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='*']"));
// or
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id)]"));
```

I'm using Java. Thanks!

UPD: The only solution for me is to get all elements by `"//*"`, go through them and get their `id` attributes. Is there a way to get all attributes at once, something like `"//*@A"` from Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Attribute A of element  where A contains 't'*

```
//E[contains(@A,'t')]/@A
```

or

```
//E[contains(@A,'t')]@A
```

*Attribute A of any element*

```
//*/@A
```

or `//*@A`

so I use java too. So if you need to find all elements with id attribute you can simply use

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath(//*@id))
```

Hope this helps you. 
ALso look [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/xpath,-css,-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone/). Nice manual for xpath and css selectors

Comment: Thanks, but I want to get `WebElements`, not attributes. The last solution would be good for me, but I'm using Java so I cannot get All attributes as Strings.

Comment: I got an Exception when using `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*@id"))`. But I found a good solution in provided manual. I'll edit your post. Thanks

Comment: Also this is my mistake, this answer is in my question. Don't know how I missed this...

Comment: it's ok) sometimes I get stuck on simple obvious things too)

Answer (score 1):

have you tried `"//*[contains(@id, '')]"`